# Access rights of a nested class of a nested class

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, inner-classes

In C++ a nested class has access rights to all members of the enclosing class. Does this also apply to a nested class of a nested class?

This code

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    class B
    {
    public:
        B() { std::cout << A::x << std::endl; }

        class C
        {
        public:
            C() { std::cout << A::x << std::endl; }

        };

    };

private:
    static const int x { 0 };

};

int main()
{
    A::B b;

    A::B::C c;
}
```

compiles without warning on g++ 7.2. However, it is unclear to me that this conforms to the standard. The standard draft (N4727 14.7) says:

> A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as any other member.

However, in the example above `C` is not a member of `A`, it is a member of a member. Is the standard ambiguous here? Is g++ behavior portable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, in the example above `C` is not a member of `A`, it is a member of a member.

Yes this is well-defined behavior; the access right is transfered from `B`.

According to the standard [[class.access]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access#2),

> A member of a class can also access all the names to which the class has access.

And [[class.mem]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#1),

> Members of a class are data members, member functions, nested types, enumerators, and member templates and specializations thereof.

`C` is a nested class of `B`, it's also the member of `B`, then `C` can access names what `B` could access to, including `A::x`. For the same reason, `C::C` is the member of `C`, it could access names what `C` could access to, so accessing `A::x` in `C::C` is fine.

Comment: Right, I figured this had to be specified somewhere. I just couldn't find the place.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is well-defined and in-line with the standard wording. What you are missing is the relevant wording of `[class.access]p2`, which strengthens that which you have already quoted:

> A member of a class can also access all the names to which the class has
>   access. A local class of a member function may access the same names that the
>   member function itself may access.

This means that the accessibility is transitive. If `C` has access to the same entities as `B`, it also means that `C` has access to the entities in `A`, as `B` has access to them.

```
class A {
  class B {
    class C {
      C() { A::x; /* well-defined */ }
    };
  };

  static int x;
};
```